# MYSQL - query to select random rows with limitation to parent id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that selects 2 random rows for each parent_id from my table.
At the moment my query always returns the first 2 id's for each parent_id. (For example: 1,2 of parent_id=1).

My table is currently as follows:

```
id, title  , parent_id
 1, Title1 ,         1
 2, Title2 ,         1
 3, Title3 ,         1
 4, Title4 ,         2
 5, Title5 ,         2 
 6, Title6 ,         2 
 7, Title7 ,         2
 8, Title8 ,         3
 9, Title9 ,         3
10, Title10,         3
```

My current query is:

```html
SELECT id,title,parent_id, rn
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@parent_id = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@parent_id := parent_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn,
             meals.*   
      FROM meals CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @parent_id := '') params
      ORDER BY rand() 
     ) meals
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I would like my result to change on each query so for example one result will return the id's 1,3 for parent_id=1 and one will return 2,3 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `order by rand()` clause into its own derived table

```
SELECT id,title,parent_id, rn
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@parent_id = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@parent_id := parent_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn,
             t1.*   
      FROM ( SELECT * FROM meals CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @parent_id := '') params
           ORDER BY rand() ) t1
      ORDER BY parent_id 
     ) meals
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY id ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3310f/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `parent_id` into the `order by`:

```
SELECT id, title, parent_id, rn
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@parent_id = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@parent_id := parent_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn,
             meals.*   
      FROM meals CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @parent_id := -1) params
      ORDER BY parent_id, rand() 
     ) meals
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

And, if `parent_id` is a number, there is no reason to make `@parent_id` a string.

Comment: still not working. I keep getting the same order of rows